# How to sequence over a connector in Modeshape

Tags: jcr, modeshape

I'm in the process of implementing Modeshape(4) as an asset repository. Currently I'm having trouble with sequencers not automatically traversing configured `externalSources` (specifically the `FileSystemConnector`).

The configuration of the 2 services are as follow:

```
...
      "externalSources": {
         "local-fs" : {
                "classname": "org.modeshape.connector.filesystem.FileSystemConnector",
                "directoryPath": "src/test/resources/repository",
                "addMimeTypeMixin": true,
                "projections": [ "default:/test => /" ]
            }
        },
        "sequencing": {
            "sequencers": {
                "Image Sequencer": {
                    "classname": "org.modeshape.sequencer.image.ImageMetadataSequencer",
                    "pathExpressions": [ "default://(*.(gif|png|pict|jpg|tiff|tif))/jcr:content[@jcr:data] => /images/$1" ]
                }
            }
        },
...
```

When running with this configuration the folder that is pinned to the `/test` node is resolved correctly and all the files which it contains are presented correctly as `nt:file` and `nt:folder` nodes.

No `image:metadata` nodes are generated from the files found under `/test/**` that fit the sequencers path expression but if I am to upload an image file (outside of the `/test` folder)  everything works as expected (the image sequencer performs sequencing).

I also made sure to perform a `reindex` on the workspace just to ensure that even after the file system connector had initialized the `image:metadata` nodes were not being created by the sequencer`.

My current work around is to manually sequence this node (which works well enough) but I would imagine this could be automated by the system and I've missed some vital configuration option. Does anyone have any incite as to how I could have the sequencer hit these files automatically, perhaps on `reindex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, the sequencers only run when there is an event signaling a change in the content. When the repository loads the external file system as nodes, these are not considered as 'new' and thus the sequencer does not run.

Feel free to join the [ModeShape community](https://community.jboss.org/en/modeshape/) and request an improvement in ModeShape to automatically run the sequencers on external partitions like this.

Comment: Thanks Mr Haunch. I'll be sure to take a look a the forums (which I should have done in the 1st place).

Thanks for your (and Mr Chiorean's) work and support on Modeshape, I've found all your comments scattered throughout the internet regarding Modeshape/JCR very concise and helpful.